# Customize "Exception Settings" background color in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, themes, color-scheme

I'm in the process of creating a VS 2015 black theme, but I'm having trouble fully blackening the background of the "Exception Settings" panel. It's grey, not black like the text editor view.

[image: Exception Settings Demonstration]

I am also having the same problem with the "Find Symbol Results" panel background, where it's grey instead of black.

[image: Find Symbol Results Demonstration]

If I blacken those two panel backgrounds the theme will be complete. Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Tools - Options - Environment - Fonts and Color. Choose the appropriate section / window and change the color. More info can be found on MSDN [How to: Change Fonts and Colors in the Editor page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165337.aspx)

Comment: I've already changed the "Item background" property for "Find Results Window" to black, but to no avail. :/